# Accessing X and Y in template class A like in template<template<int X, int Y> class> class A;

Tags: c++, templates

What is the correct syntax to use template parameters of a template class argument in another template class?

For example: How can I access X and Y of class Param in class Foo?

Program:

```
template < template < int, int > class X1>
struct Foo {
int foo() {
printf("ok%d %d\n", X1::X, X1::Y);
return 0;
}};

template < int X, int Y >
class Param {
int x,y;
public:
Param(){x=X; y=Y;}
void printParam(){
cout<<x<<" "<<y<<"\n";
}
};

int main() {
Param<10, 20> p;
p.printParam();
Foo< Param > tt;
tt.foo();
return 0;
}
```

As such for the above code, for the printf statement compiler complains:

```
In member function 'int Foo<X1>::foo()':
Line 4: error: 'template<int <anonymous>, int <anonymous> > class X1' used without template parameters
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. The template template parameter means that you take a template name **without supplied template arguments**.

```
Foo< Param > tt;
```

Here you can see that no values are supplied for `Param`. You'd take a template template parameter so that Foo itself could instantiate `Params` with any arguments it likes.

Example:

```
template < template < int, int > class X1>
struct Foo {

    X1<1, 2> member;

    X1<42, 100> foo();
};

template <int N, int P> struct A {};

template <int X, int Y> struct B {};

Foo<A> a_foo;  //has a member of type A<1, 2>, foo returns A<42, 100>
Foo<B> b_foo; //has a member of type B<1, 2>, foo returns B<42, 100>
```

---

But if you want your `Foo` to output those integers, it has to take real types, not templates. Secondly, the names of the template arguments (`X` and `Y`) are only meaningful where they are in scope. They are otherwise completely arbitrary identifiers. You can retrieve the values with simple metaprogramming:

```
#include <cstdio>

template <class T>
struct GetArguments;

//partial specialization to retrieve the int parameters of a T<int, int>
template <template <int, int> class T, int A, int B>
struct GetArguments<T<A, B> >
{
   enum {a = A, b = B};
};
//this specialization also illustrates another use of template template parameters:
//it is used to pick out types that are templates with two int arguments

template <class X1>
struct Foo {
  int foo() {
    printf("ok%d %d\n", GetArguments<X1>::a, GetArguments<X1>::b);
    return 0;
  }
};

template < int X, int Y >
class Param {
public:
   void print();
};

//this is to illustrate X and Y are not essential part of the Param template
//in this method definition I have chosen to call them something else
template <int First, int Second> 
void Param<First, Second>::print()
{
   printf("Param<%d, %d>\n", First, Second);
}

int main() {

    Foo< Param<10, 20> > tt;
    tt.foo();
    Param<10, 20> p;
    p.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This here is an example what could work as well:

```
template < typename X1>
struct Foo;

template < template < int, int > class X1, int X, int Y >
struct Foo< X1<X,Y> > {
    int foo() {
        printf("ok%d %d\n", X, Y);
        return 0;
    }
};

template < int X, int Y >
class Param {
    int x,y;
public:
    Param(){x=X; y=Y;}
    void printParam(){
        cout<<x<<" "<<y<<"\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    Param<10, 20> p;
    p.printParam();
    Foo< Param<30,40> > tt;
    tt.foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't take template parameters of a template class argument, since the argument is a template without parameters. You can do this instead:

```
template < typename X1 >
struct Foo;

template < template < int, int > class X1, int A, int B >
struct Foo< X1< A, B > >
{
    ... here you can use A and B directly, or X1< A, B >::X and X1< A, B >::Y ...
};
```

You specify the template to take a single type, and specialize it for the case of a template taking two `int` arguments. With that definition, you would use it like this:

```
Foo< Param< 0, 1 > > tt;
```